# HERE maps: More styles for Vector tile rendering with MapBox/Maplibre

Tags: here-api

I'm using mapbox-gl-js library (soon maplibre-gls-js) to render Maps from HERE Vector Tiles API using the styles from https://github.com/apollo-mapping/ap-tilezen-mapbox-styles

I saw and tried this example from HERE: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/vector-tiles
where they offer their own style that can be used with the mapbox library:

```
https://assets.vector.hereapi.com/styles/berlin/base/mapbox/tilezen?apikey=
```

But I have not found any documentation on the styles endpoint.

Are there more styles available I can choose from? This "berlin" style is a bit too dark for my taste.

Comment: If I am not wrong you can fully customize the style with this online tool: https://heremaps.github.io/harp-map-editor/ - There is also this tool: https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/, which is using the Vector Tile API documented here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/vector-tile-api/dev_guide/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't have more styles for Mapbox render engine therefore you need to create/rework you own.

The defined style on `https://assets.vector.hereapi.com/styles/berlin/base/mapbox/tilezen?apikey=` should be compatible with Mapbox Style Specification https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/

If you open this `https://assets.vector.hereapi.com/styles/berlin/base/mapbox/tilezen?apikey=` directly then you can see 'layers' property that compatible with the description on https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/

E.g. each layer object has property 'id' that is mapped to Mapbox layer id and layer object has a property 'source-layer' layer id to use from a HERE Vector tile source (description on https://developer.here.com/documentation/vector-tiles-api/dev_guide/topics/layers.html and https://developer.here.com/documentation/vector-tiles-api/dev_guide/topics/layers.html#tile-layers).

To find layer ids of Mapbox use this description https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/layer/#finding-layer-ids

To find layer ids of HERE Tiles use it https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/

Using 'filter' property https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#filter for define an expression specifying conditions on source (HERE Vector Tile) features.

Basically you need to rework color styles in the `https://assets.vector.hereapi.com/styles/berlin/base/mapbox/tilezen?apikey=` and save it to your's internet resources